# Different application installers return a 1603 file access error; how to find file that it cannot access?

Tags: windows-10, installation, windows-installer

On Windows 10 v2004, two application installers fail [Evernote and Windows SDK] with `MainEngineThread is returning 1603` via:

```
Error 1603: A fatal error occurred during installation
```

- According to [Microsoft Docs](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/834484/you-receive-an-error-1603-a-fatal-error-occurred-during-installation), the application's installer cannot access a file, but I am capturing the installer's PID with Process Monitor and I do not see any `ACCESS DENIED` errors to the file system.

How do I determine which file neither of the installers can access?

Comment: Try just one installer on one Windows 10 installation. I think you will find that works much better. I have not ever needed more than one.

Comment: These are installers of different products. I tried to install Evernote and winsdk.

Comment: You should not need a different Windows installer for different products. One will do. Your question says different Windows installers. Do you mean installer for the Product? You may wish to edit your question to clarify.

Comment: I've done edits but is it even possible to have 2 Windows installers on 1 system?

Comment: @Taras Your question is improperly worded for what you're asking, as the way you've worded it is coming across like you're trying to install Windows when what you're trying to do is install two **_programs_**, [Evernote](https://evernote.com/) and the [Windows SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk/).  Please edit your question accordingly, else you're going to continue to have the question misinterpreted.

Comment: You cannot have two different Windows Installers on one Windows system. Windows does not work that way. If you have problems installing software, there is something fundamentally wrong with your system. You may wish to back up Windows, reinstall Windows, and then try installing software normally .

Comment: @Taras Ensure prior to launching either installer that all instances & services for both [Evernote & Windows SDK components] have been terminated via Task Manager [`CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`ESC`]. If you're not trying to update them & are installing for the first time, ensure each installer is launched with Admin privileges, but if that doesn't work, you're going to need to review the installer's log file or launch the installer with the logging parameter set _(easiest to do with a `.msi` installer `name.msi /?`, as many installers using `.exe` don't support additional parameters: `name.exe /?`)_

Comment: I close all installers before running another one. Installer is the only program that run on my PC. I run installer as Admin. First I run CMD as admin and from it I start installer. I've generated verbose log output but I do not see any problems there. I only see 1603 error. I tried to attach log file to question, but I can't do it, because log file is big.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error 1603 means that another installer is already running,
or that a reboot is required after a previous installation,
or that the folder that you are trying to install to is encrypted
(the last one needs to be fixed by you).

Reboot and retry one installation.

If error 1603 happens again, disable your anti-virus and try again.

If again this didn't work, and you have the offline version of the installer,
try it again after booting in Safe mode.

Comment: It was a metter of simple reboot:) Evernote is already installed on my PC.